# Javascript regular expression can't split

Tags: javascript, regex

I have some text like

```
<<<<((((sports====1000))))>>>>
```

or

```
<<<<((((sports====1000))))((((librarys====2000))))>>>>
```

my problem is I have get the text from this like

```
text[0][0] = 'sports';
text[0][1] = '1000';
text[1][0] = 'library';
text[1][1] = '2000';
```

any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Need some more clarity on what exactly do you want?

Comment: check out my answer. and tell me if its working !

Comment: @HashimR I can't accept your ans because i have done not exactly but something like that. I want a more optimized solution. Felix Kling I have tried so far, is first i have the text within <<<<((((text))))>>>> than i have done some testing to check whether it is a single row or not by testing ))))(((( than i have splitted again by ==== than i got records. Sachin Shanbhag I like to grab the from strings like <<<<((((sp====1000))))>>>> one record or <<<<((((s====1000))))((((l====2000))))>>>> multiple record or <<<<((((libr====))))>>>> some entities can be empty any characters there can be.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to split on everything but the content and then remove the empty elements in the array.

```
s="<<<<((((sports====1000))))((((librarys====2000))))>>>>";
s.split(/[<()>=]/).filter(function(ele){if (ele!="") return true});
=> ["sports", "1000", "librarys", "2000"]
```

This is kind of a hack and since I don't know the syntax of your text this might or might not work out for you.

Yet another hack:

```
s="<<<<((((sports====1000))))((((librarys====2000))))((((no_value====))))>>>>";
arr = s.replace("====)","====nil").
  split(/[<\(\)>=]/).
  filter(function(ele){if (ele!="") return true});
var res=[]; 
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i+=2) { res.push([arr[i],arr[i+1]]); }
res
=> [["sports", "1000"], ["librarys", "2000"], ["no_value", "nil"]]
```

Comment: only works if the elements don't contain `<`,`>`,`(`,`)`,`=` by it self. I guess the reason these separators are repeated 4 times could be to allow these characters (repeated less than 4 times) ;-) within the element data... beside this small objection I consider this a great solution.

Comment: It did work to some extend but when sorry that i didn't mention the text can be <<<<((((sports====))))((((librarys====2000))))>>>> means the amount can be null for that it didn't work and i did mention that i like to have it like a row record than it will be helpful to show result also can you explain the second line(s.split(/[<()>=]/).filter(function(ele){if (ele!="") return true});) of your code as I am a newbie

Comment: it can contain any element. But the number of element will not be the same. Like in '<<<<((((sports====1000))))((((librarys====2000))))>>>>' there not will be '<<<<((((sports========))))((((librarys====2000))))>>>>' or '<<<<((((sports========))))((((((((====2000))))>>>>'

Comment: I tried to explain the way it works in the answer but I can do another try .split(/[<()>=]/) splits the string to an array on every occurrence of <, (, ), and >. test="(1)2<3<(" would become ["", "1", "2", "3", "", ""]. Then it removes (filters) all elements in the array that are empty. That leaves the content. This method will not work if the data isn't always key=value. If there is a key but no value, it will break.

Comment: The /[<()>=]/ is a regular expression. http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Answer (score 0):

regex to get the elements could look like this:

```
\({4}(.+?)={4}(.+?)\){4}
```

see [this example](http://www.myregextester.com/?r=6f74e0ec)

Comment: did u try your solution ? I tried it before it will search greedily when I will apply for <<<<((((sports====1000))))((((librarys====2000))))>>>> it will return the whole ((((sports====1000))))((((librarys====2000))))

Comment: `.+` is greedy but `.+?` as I noted is reluctant (non greedy).  see the linked example...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
var test  = "<<<<((((sports=====))))((((====2000))))((((hall====2000))))>>>>";
textAfterSplit1 = test.split(/[(<>)]/);

var myarray = [];

for (i=0; i <(textAfterSplit1.length); i++){
    textAfterSplit2 = textAfterSplit1[i].split(/[=]/);
    if (textAfterSplit2[0] == null){
        textAfterSplit2[0]= "";
    }
    if (textAfterSplit2[1] == null) {
        textAfterSplit2[1]= ""; 
    }
    myarray.push([textAfterSplit2[0],textAfterSplit2[1]]);
}

document.write(myarray[0][0]);
document.write(myarray[0][1]);
document.write(myarray[1][0]);
document.write(myarray[1][1]);
```

Intended output is:

```
sports2000
```

Its working in all scenarios. Hope this might help. Cheers!